# Get all app services and the inbound IP address

Tags: azure, powershell

There has to be a better way to get the Name, hostname, and the inbound IP address.

Here is the script I did, it works but it takes forever. Can someone help me with a better way. I'm not very good at PowerShell.

```
$getwebapps= Get-AzWebApp

foreach($getwebapp in $getwebapps)
 {

$webappsrg=(Get-AzWebApp).ResourceGroup
$webapps=(Get-AzWebApp).Name
$functionApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $webappsrg -ResourceName $webapps -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites 

$functionApp.Properties.defaultHostName
$functionApp.Properties.inboundipaddress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shared script you are using `get-AzWebapp` cmdlet multiple times which is taking more time to query all the webapp's under the subscription.

You can change the script to below which might take the lesser time when compared to earlier.

```
$getwebapps= Get-AzWebApp

foreach($getwebapp in $getwebapps)
 {
$functionApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $getwebapp.resourcegroup -ResourceName $getwebapp.Name -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites 

Write-Host $functionApp.Properties.Name,$functionApp.Properties.defaultHostName,$functionApp.Properties.inboundipaddress 
}
```

I have tested the above script in the cloud shell and it is working fine.